# How I can export to make diferents pages for one web site and put the pictures? ps: i'm new in dev

Tags: javascript, html, image, export

The code for the pics and what it does(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6scZ.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELHbY.png)

[the code for export and what it does(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IClGb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbp4v.png)

thank you for your help I'm learning we can do a video call if it's better.

I try to put some pics and it appears like i the screeshoot on my web site and add pages where I have a "Cannot GET /galerie"...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.